# How to train 3D CNN for regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, regression

I am working on 3D CNN to predict numerical values of rock permeability with regression, so i will do the features extraction with the 3D CNN and output with regression.

i Have Built the database of 2178 3D BINARY(only 0 and 1) images(.raw) with shape of (200,200,200), and i have .csv file containing all 3d images filenames and their permeability values
I've written the code but it didn't work, when i launch the training it stuck at epoch 1
here is the full code :

NB: I'm new to ML and DL

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import keras_preprocessing
from keras_preprocessing import image
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.set_printoptions(precision=4)
np.random.seed(10)

# import nibabel as nib

# from scipy import ndimage


def read_raw_file(filepath):
    """Read and load volume"""
    patch_file = np.fromfile(filepath, dtype=np.uint8)
    patch_im = (patch_file.reshape(200,200,200))
    patch_im = patch_im==1;
    return patch_im


# def resize_volume(img):
#     """Resize across z-axis"""
#     # Set the desired depth
#     desired_depth = 200
#     desired_width = 200
#     desired_height = 200
#     # Get current depth
#     current_depth = img.shape[-1]
#     current_width = img.shape[0]
#     current_height = img.shape[1]
#     # Compute depth factor
#     depth = current_depth / desired_depth
#     width = current_width / desired_width
#     height = current_height / desired_height
#     depth_factor = 1 / depth
#     width_factor = 1 / width
#     height_factor = 1 / height
#     # Rotate
#     img = ndimage.rotate(img, 90, reshape=False)
#     # Resize across z-axis
#     img = ndimage.zoom(img, (width_factor, height_factor, depth_factor), order=1)
#     return img


def process_scan(path):
    """Read and resize volume"""
    # Read scan
    volume = read_raw_file(path)
#     # Normalize
#     volume = normalize(volume)
#     # Resize width, height and depth
#     volume = resize_volume(volume)
    return volume

dataset_paths = [
    os.path.join("./patches", x)
    for x in os.listdir("patches")
]

print("CT scans: " + str(len(dataset_paths)))

# Read and process the scans.
# Each scan is passed by above preprocessing helper fucntions.
images_dataset = np.array([process_scan(path) for path in dataset_paths])
print(len(images_dataset))

#assigning labels
df = pd.read_csv(
    "./training_data.csv", 
    sep=";")
df.sort_values(["Images"],axis=0, ascending=True,inplace=True,na_position='first')
perm_vals=df['Permeability'].values

dataset_labels= np.array(perm_vals)

# Split data in the ratio 80%-20% for training and validation.
TRAIN_PCT = 0.8
TRAIN_CUT = int(len(df) * TRAIN_PCT)
x_train = images_dataset[:TRAIN_CUT]
y_train = dataset_labels[:TRAIN_CUT]
x_val = images_dataset[TRAIN_CUT:]
y_val = dataset_labels[TRAIN_CUT:]
print(
    "Number of samples in train and validation are %d and %d."
    % (x_train.shape[0], x_val.shape[0])
)

import random

from scipy import ndimage

dtype=tf.float32
@tf.function
def rotate(volume):
    """Rotate the volume by a few degrees"""

    def scipy_rotate(volume):
        # define some rotation angles
        angles = [-20, -10, -5, 5, 10, 20]
        # pick angles at random
        angle = random.choice(angles)
        # rotate volume
        volume = ndimage.rotate(volume, angle, reshape=False)
        volume[volume < 0] = 0
        volume[volume > 1] = 1
        return volume

    augmented_volume = tf.numpy_function(scipy_rotate, [volume], tf.bool)
    return augmented_volume


def train_preprocessing(volume, label):
    """Process training data by rotating and adding a channel."""
    # Rotate volume
#     volume = rotate(volume)
    volume = tf.expand_dims(volume, axis=3)
    return volume, label


def validation_preprocessing(volume, label):
    """Process validation data by only adding a channel."""
    volume = tf.expand_dims(volume, axis=3)
    return volume, label

# Define data loaders.
train_loader = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
validation_loader = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_val, y_val))

batch_size = 1
# Augment the on the fly during training.
train_dataset = (
#     train_loader.shuffle(len(x_train))
    train_loader.map(train_preprocessing)
    .batch(batch_size)
    .prefetch(2)
)
# Only rescale.
validation_dataset = (
#     validation_loader.shuffle(len(x_val))
    validation_loader.map(validation_preprocessing)
    .batch(batch_size)
    .prefetch(2)
)

def get_model(width=200, height=200, depth=200):
    """Build a 3D convolutional neural network model."""

    inputs = keras.Input((width, height, depth, 1))

    x = layers.Conv3D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(inputs)
    x = layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=2)(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

    x = layers.Conv3D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(x)
    x = layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=2)(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

    x = layers.Conv3D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(x)
    x = layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=2)(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

    x = layers.Conv3D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(x)
    x = layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=2)(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling3D()(x)
    x = layers.Dense(units=512, activation="relu")(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)

    outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation="linear")(x)

    # Define the model.
    model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name="3dcnn")
    return model


# Build model.
model = get_model(width=200, height=200, depth=200)
model.summary()

# Compile model.
initial_learning_rate = 0.0001
lr_schedule = keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate, decay_steps=100000, decay_rate=0.96, staircase=True
)
model.compile(
    loss="binary_crossentropy",
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule),
    metrics=["acc"],
)

# Define callbacks.
checkpoint_cb = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    "3d_image_classification.h5", save_best_only=True
)
early_stopping_cb = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_acc", patience=15)

# Train the model, doing validation at the end of each epoch
epochs = 100
model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    validation_data=validation_dataset,
    epochs=epochs,
    shuffle=True,
    verbose=2,
    callbacks=[checkpoint_cb, early_stopping_cb],
)
```

And the training stuck here :
[Training stuck image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGY4C.png)

Comment: 3D convolution is a heavy task, you need a good GPU to do it in fast times, are you working on a CPU, if the answer is yes the program is probably not stuck, just really really slow :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from the fact that in your model.fit, you specified the parameter verbose=2.

This means that your code will only output messages at the end of an epoch, not informative ones during training progress.

To solve your problem and see training progress, set verbose=1

You can refer to this [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LRhAo-ocTT6lhFQbJaNElycX0YgFk5AU#scrollTo=Z90aNkddV_Qn) and copy the notebook in your environment and run the code again.

I have removed the redundant functions from the code.